# Question regarding the genitive and "bestimmte" articles

Tags: article, genitive

Simple question:

I have seen people saying this in different ways, but the correct way of writing it in terms of standard German would be:

> Am Anfang dieses Jahres
>
> Am Anfang jedes Jahres
>
> Am Ende jenes Sommers

etc.

correct?

And the reason for that is because:

1. Dies-(or any other articles with d in the beginning such as dasselbe, dasjenige, etc.)
2. Jen-, jed- (or any other articles with j in the beginning.)
3. Manch-
4. Solch-
5. Welch-
6. Alle
7. Beide
8. Plural of "keine" and any other possessivarticles (meine, seine, deine, etc.)

They all ^ act and are "dekliniert" the same way as the "bestimmten" articles (der/die/das/die(pl.)) and not like an adjective, right?

Thank you!

Edit: examples:

> Jeder schlechte Film
>
> Welcher gute Film hast du dieses Jahr gesehen?
>
> Welche guten Filme hast du dieses Jahr gesehen?
>
> Das Verhalten solcher guten Person muss belohnt werden.

are they correct?

Comment: "Welcher gute Film hast du dieses Jahr gesehen?" -> Accusative: "Welchen guten Film hast du dieses Jahr gesehen?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pronouns have their own peculiar declination schemes.

And you will hear

> Am Anfang diese**n** Jahres

quite often. I think that's because the nominative neutrum of this pronoun is also *dies**es*** and using the nominative form for genitive just sounds wrong.

---

> Welche**n** gute**n** Film hast du dieses Jahr gesehen?

You are asking about an accusative object.

> Das Verhalten solch **ein**er guten Person muss belohnt werden.

*Solch* is a tricky word. The singular isn't a pronoun but a qualifier so it needs an additional counter. For singular *ein*.

> Das Verhalten einer solch guten Person muss belohnt werden.

Here, *solch* doesn't qualify the counter *ein* but the adjective *gut*. The meaning is slightly different.

Comment: Ah but standardly speaking, the correct form is indeed "Am Anfang des/dieses Jahres" right? I'm actually pretty sure the dies qualifies as an article. As for your other points, I totally agree with. Just one question though, another alternative for that sentence then would be "Das Verhalten solcher guten PersonEN."  Then? Aside from that, the rules that I wrote above are indeed correct, no?

Comment: And also, are there any other mistakes I stated that I should watch out for?

Comment: Yes, *dieses* is grammatically correct for genitive. But almost everybody I know uses *diesen* instead for neutral genitive.

Comment: You can use *solcher* in plural, yes.

Comment: As I wrote, the pronouns are peculiar. Most forms are the same as those of the definite article but there are exceptions.